# .Split("//") is also picking up "/"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am delimiting my data with the "//" as I am passing it up to my webservice.  My webservice is splitting the data into an array like so:

```
myArray = al(i).ToString.Split("//")
```

Everything works great, however, if I pass in some data like this: 100/100 then that also gets split.  Is there a way to make sure that only the "//" gets split?

Comment: why are you passing the data to the webservice with '//' as the delim, instead of ';' or ',' or '|'?

Comment: ...is this VB.NET? Sounds like it might be using the wrong overload due to built-in idiocy. Upgrade to C# today to get rid of this problem. You should also upgrade to a more robust way of passing multiple values, say, using an array. Most web service implementations should be able to pass that quite fine.

Comment: Well we have text that gets passed in so I wanted to make sure that I didn't pass in something as the delimiter.  However the '|' might work well.  And yes this is VB.Net.  I updated the question to include that information.

Comment: C# isn't an upgrade from VB.NET.

Comment: i would recommend changing the delim to '|' it is more of a standard, and easier to work with.

Comment: @Matti - they are both modern OO languages that work with the .NET Framework. Use whichever you like. They both have pros and cons.

Comment: @george - thanks I will make the change.  However, I'll leave the question open until an answer is found.

Comment: @Jon B: I don't think it's fair to say that they both have pros and cons when VB.NET only has cons.

Comment: This kind of datatype mismatch between the language and the framework seems like quite a serious con to me!

Comment: @bobince: Tell me about it. Every time I have to subject myself to VB code I end up getting ridiculous errors due to the built-in type coercion which makes no sense.

Comment: @Matti - Let's not have an argument about which programming language is better. The point of Stack Overflow is to answer questions, not to scold people for having different opinions, preferences or needs.

Comment: @Jon B: I reject your opinions, preferences and needs and continue promoting those of my own!

Comment: No, *let's* have an argument about which programming language is better! With the help of advanced science, we can solve this matter once and for all! And the result is: the best programming language is FORTRAN. What? How the hell did that happen?

Comment: If you use `Option Strict` the VB compiler produces an error rather than choosing the unhelpful overload. Always, always use `Option Strict`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The VB.Net compiler is converting your string into a `Char` array and calling [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).
Thus, it's splitting on either `/` or `/`.

You need to call [the overload that takes a `string` array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx), like this:

```
"100/100".Split(New String() { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: AH! That took me a second to figure out. That's just plain *nasty*! The string is really a character array containing '/' and '/'. YIKES!

Comment: Should the example be "100//100" ?

Comment: @izb: No.  He specifically wants that string to not split.

Comment: indeed, he recently added the vb.net tag, +1 regardless

Comment: Thanks all, this worked great!  I appreciate all the tips too!

Comment: +1 and if you use `Option Strict` the [VB compiler will give an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773618/split-is-also-picking-up/3780058#3780058) rather than choosing this unhelpful overload

Answer (score 2):

Always, always use **[Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(VS.71).aspx)**.

With `Option Strict` the original code produces an error, rather than choosing the unhelpful overload:

> Error 1 Option Strict On disallows
>   implicit conversions from 'String' to
>   'Char'.

Comment: Thank you for that answer and will make that change in my code.  I'm a little confused as to why "//" isn't a string in the 1st place?  If you have a reference that I can read up on this issue that would be great!  Also what would you have done if you had gotten this error?

Comment: @Jeff If I had got the error, I would have checked the available overloads for Split and seen that there wasn't one that accepts a string. I hope I would then have figured out another way to get the result I wanted. My answer has a link to the docs on   Option Strict, that's a good starting point.